# React state lost when user refreshes page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React/Node and working on a learning project. It's a platform that connects users (freelancers) with nonprofit companies. When a user logs in, they can view a list of companies and click a button to connect with that company. They can then go to the UserConnections page to view all the companies they connected with.

When they click the 'connect' button, the connection is made in the database, and the button becomes disabled. This is currently working correctly.. unless you refresh the page, in which case the button becomes clickable again.

I'm probably not using state correctly. I'm tracking two different states. The first is when it's a "fresh" connection the user just made. The second is when they visit their UserConnections page, I'm retrieving their "old" connections from the database.

What can I do to make sure the state of a connection persists if the user refreshes the page, or if they come back later? My code is below (shortened to only include relevant code)

**App.js**

```
function App() {

  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
  const [connectionHandles, setConnectionHandles] = useState([]);

//   Check if connected to this company 
  function hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle) {
    return connectionHandles.includes(companyHandle);
  }

//   Make the connection in the database
  function connectToCompany(companyHandle) {
    if (hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle)) return;
    VolunteerApi.connectToCompany(currentUser.username, companyHandle);
    setConnectionHandles([...connectionHandles, companyHandle]);
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <UserContext.Provider value={{ connectionHandles, setConnectionHandles, currentUser, setCurrentUser, hasConnectedToCompany, connectToCompany }}>
        <div>
          <Navigation />
          <Routes />
        </div>
      </UserContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**CompanyDetail.js**

```
function CompanyDetail() {
  const { companyHandle } = useParams();
  const [company, setCompany] = useState(null);

  const { currentUser, hasConnectedToCompany, connectToCompany } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState();

  React.useEffect(function updateConnectedStatus() {
    setConnected(hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle));
  }, [companyHandle, hasConnectedToCompany]);
  

//   Handle connect 
  async function handleConnect(evt) {
    if (hasConnectedToCompany(companyHandle)) return;
    connectToCompany(companyHandle);
    setConnected(true);

    let connectUserInDb;
    try {
      connectUserInDb = await VolunteerApi.connectToCompany(currentUser.username, companyHandle);
    } catch (err) {
      setFormErrors(err);
      return;
    }
  }

  if (currentUser) {
    return (
      <div>         
            <h1>{company.companyName}</h1>            
            <p>
              <button onClick={handleConnect} disabled={connected}> {connected ? "Connected" : "Connect"} </button>              
            </p>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

**UserConnections.js**

```
function UserConnections() {
  const { currentUser, connectionHandles } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    const connections = currentUser.connections.concat(connectionHandles);
    const comps = connections.map((c) => VolunteerApi.getCurrentCompany(c));
    Promise.all(comps).then(comps => isMounted && setCompanies(comps));
    return () => { isMounted = false };
  }, [currentUser, connectionHandles]);

  if (!companies || companies.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>You have no connections</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Connections</h1>
          {companies && companies.map(c => (
            <CompanyCard
              key={c.companyHandle}
              companyHandle={c.companyHandle}
              companyName={c.companyName}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Correct, state does not persist. Your database does however, so all you need to do is load the state from the database when your app mounts. Not sure what you mean by "old" state, each state change should immediately be stored in the DB, or you *will* lose it on refresh. If you have two pages/components that are supposed to show DB state, you need to load the DB state in both components or the common parent.

Answer (score 0):

the state will reset when the page refreshes, but you can either use the DB to save the connection, or use local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, State is lost with React when you Refresh the page.

You should use another method to keep this information even if the user refresh the page. Here are the options:

- In the database. Could work if the user is behind an authentification (Login password). Example User `name: Paul`, `id; 3131`, did click on the button "connect". In your database, you add a column in the table `User` called `userConnect = true`
- In the url. As soon as the user click on the button "connect" you change the URL with `React router`. For example the URL was `mydomain.com`, and after clicking it becomes `mydomain.com?clicked=true`. If the user refresh your page, you still have the information about the user who clicked on the button.
- In a cookie (More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- In local Storage  (More info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/local)